# Inconsistent linear system from matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I do not how to write matrices using Latex, so I just attach the problem instead. [image]

Why is this linear system inconsistent? 
Trying to solve the system, at least I found $y=\frac{1}{10}$. But I know that we have one free varible, as we do not have $m=n$.

Comment: Think of this as two equations.  Divide the top equation (both sides) by $5$ and the bottom equation by $2$ and make conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

write it as
$$
\begin{cases}
5(x-y-z)=4\\
2(x-y-z)=2
\end{cases}
\quad \iff \quad
\begin{cases}
(x-y-z)=\frac{4}{5}\\
(x-y-z)=1
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I dunno if I'd call that a "hint."

Comment: Ok. So I found $1=\frac{4}{5}$ by substituting $x=1+y+z$ in for the first equation, and this is not possible. Is this proof enough to conclude that the system is inconsistent?

Comment: @Mataunited17 Forsooth.  Tis verily.

Comment: Are inconsistency and "one solution" mutually exclusive?

Comment: @Mataunited17 Yes.  It follows from the fact that $0\ne 1$.